# How to zoom on hover with Django-Oscar image

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-oscar

I am using Django-Oscar with AWS S3 to host my product images. The carousel that displays images is presenting the product images correctly, but it is showing the thumbnail size image. I want to display the full-size image, not the thumbnail, on hover or click.

I am using `django-compressor` as well, so the images are stored in the `cache` folder on S3.

Should I change the template to enable this, or is there a django-oscar setting that can handle this?

Relevant [code](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/templates/oscar/catalogue/partials/gallery.html):

```
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            {% for image in all_images %}
                <div class="item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    {% thumbnail image.original "440x400" upscale=False as thumb %}
                    <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ product.get_title }}" />
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

To something like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                {% for image in all_images %}
                    <div class="item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{ image.url }}" target="_blank">
                        {% thumbnail image.original "440x400" upscale=False as thumb %}
                        <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ product.get_title }}" />
                    </a>
                        {% endthumbnail %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
```